# PostgreSQL hstore - Error when storing data with different types

Tags: python, postgresql, hstore

I am using PostGreSQL 9.2 with the hstore extension 1.1

I have a python dict which is containing data with different types ie. integer and char.

```
dict = {"type": 1 , "precision": 0 , "width": 20 , "name": "test" }
```

When saving this dict into an hstore field, I got an error with the data "test" because its not an integer.

If I save all data in char, there would be no error

```
dict = {"type": "1" , "precision": "0" , "width": "20" , "name": "test" }
```

Is it normal that I could only have data with a unique type in an hstore field? Is there a way to store data with different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hstore Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html) says:

> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of
>   key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. Keys and values are
>   simply **text strings**.

If you want to interpret keys/values as not strings you should do it in Python:

- convert your keys/values to string before saving them to db
- do the reverse operation when fetching data from db